# Module loading and Apache mod-php performance

Tags: php, apache

When using loadable modules such as geoip, is there a performance hit to always loading the module in php.ini ? In other words, is there a performance *advantage* to using `dl()` if the module in question is not used very often ?

BTW, I am aware `dl()` has been removed in PHP 5.3, just wondering about the performance implications should we decide to remove this function from our code base.

Comment: is it a certain bottleneck of your application?

Comment: No, not a bottleneck. Actually I am seeing this as a problem and want to get rid of all the dl's in the code base, but want to make sure performance won't be adversly affected first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dl() makes no sense. PHP can control modules on the fly without lose performance, so loading with dl() has no more sense - I see dl() only as a facility way to load modules.

Ok, some people will be angry because shared hosts cannot gain access to php.ini to their users, but anyway...